# Resources for Inquiry-based Projects with Undergraduates

Tags: undergraduate-education, undergraduate-research, inquiry-based-learning

I am teaching an undergraduate course which consists entirely of exploratory projects on any interesting mathematical topic. I'm looking for projects where a first-year student who has only taken calculus can make discoveries within an hour, and an advanced undergraduate thinking about graduate school can continue even after twenty hours. I prefer projects where students can do short investigations, make conjectures, and then try to prove them (or run computations).

So far I have found the book [The Joy of SET](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10824.html), which I think is ideal for such projects. I am also thinking about projects on prime numbers, cellular automata, and lattice paths.

I would like additional resources that I can work from, where the authors have already thought out how to prompt students to explore topics with particular low-hanging fruit in mind, and tons more fruit beyond it.

To be clear, I'm not looking for textbooks for students to read themselves as in [Recommendations for inquiry based/aided discovery textbooks](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/4118/7707), although I got some ideas there ([Indra's Pearls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_Pearls_%28book%29)). I also got some ideas from [Topics for Discovery-based Projects](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/8294/7707), such as [Julia Robinson Mathematics Festivals](http://jrmf.org/problems.php).

Comment: (At first I thought this was a calculus course, but then it sounded like a problems course. It's not completely clear.) I am loving the book Measurrement, by Paul Lockhart. It has so many questions, and each one can take you to others. (It is not a textbook.) The JRMF has has much material, I'm curious that it's not providing you enough for the whole course.

Comment: I edited to clarify that this is not a calculus course, but has just calculus as a prerequisite. Thanks for the ideas @SueVanHattum! The JRMF does have some great ideas (and I have not gone through them all yet). Many of them are too small for my course, but I have found some gems so far.

Comment: 'Computations' made me think of https://projecteuler.net/

Answer (score 3):

[*Student Research Projects in Calculus*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883855038)

[*Cameos For Calculus*](http://www.maa.org/press/books/cameos-for-calculus-visualization-in-the-first-year-course)

I particularly like the first one because the authors include with each project a description of how long it may take a student, any issues they've encountered, and (sometimes) how it can be explored further.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question and I should say Inquiry-based Project is taking my attention. So, I really like these books:

> Tanton, J.(2001). *Solve this: math activities for students and clubs*.
>   Cambridge University Press.
>
> Cofman, J. (1990). *What to Solve?: Problems and Suggestions for Young
>   Mathematicians*. Oxford University Press, New York.

I hope these resources could help you.