# Number theory for self-study students: books and computer languages

Tags: number-theory, inquiry-based-learning

Sometimes students will contact me, as my email is visible. This time, an undergraduate in Sri Lanka has no number theory courses available and is self-studying.

My own experience is that it helps to run computer experiments; that is how I learned the topic. I took a course in C++ some twenty years ago, and that has served me well. Steep learning curve, though. It helped a good deal when I found I could use the GMP library for large integers. My impression is that many current computer languages have large integers built in.

What computer languages might one recommend for, say, investigations in number theory?

As far as books, she is currently reading Burton. I have requested that and Burn, *A Pathway into Number Theory*, from my library. The one thing I would add to early number theory is quadratic forms, maybe just binary, before attempting quadratic fields. I like that Burns does the automorphism group of a binary quadratic form; he may not call it a group, not sure yet.

[Recommendations for inquiry based/aided discovery textbooks](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/recommendations-for-inquiry-based-aided-discovery-textbooks)

Comment: I have said it many times. Just in case I haven't said it to you: I totally enjoyed [Joe Robert's *Elementary number theory - a problem oriented approach*](https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Number-Theory-Oriented-Approach/dp/0262680289) when I was an advanced high schooler. No theorems, just definitions and exercises that cover proofs broken into smaller parts (as well as examples). Of course, one could also do wonders with a suitable CAS and material prepared for that. Roberts book is pre-computer era, so may not be exactly what you need.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen new one on me, looks good. I was able to download from https://archive.org/details/ElementaryNumberTheory_841

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. You're unclear what your question is. Are you asking for a recommendation on how to self study number theory?

Comment: @Timothy I suppose I was at the time. Note that Jyrki, for example, knows me well from MSE and has a pretty good idea what I might be hoping this student would study.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend Python combined with [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/), as already recommended by Joseph O'Rourke, or rather SageMath and Python comes naturally.

Python is a modern, and widely used, interpreted language (no compilation needed) it supports big integers via the bignum type. (But using SageMath I think this is tangential, I mention it for completeness mainly.)

SageMath is a free CAS  whose user language is essentially Python. 
SageMath has lots of number theory functionality; its founder William A. Stein is a number theorist.

He also  wrote a nice book ["Elementary Number Theory: Primes, Congruences, and Secrets"](http://wstein.org/ent/) that uses this software; you can check it out on his site.

As you mentioned PARI/gp you might be interested to know that PARI is an integral part of SageMath.

Comment: Yes, I get a good deal of mileage out of pari, although I still do not know how to write multi-line programs in pari. I do know how to do big programs in Magma, but the language developed some strange storage problems at the msri installation and I could no longer run a program for months at a time. Naturally, the people who maintain Magma were unable to duplicate the problem there in Sydney.

Comment: @pjs36  this is the book page  http://wstein.org/ent/

Comment: @pjs36 yes, it was an error, I meant to link to the page Will  Jagy gives. It's fixed now.

Comment: @WillJagy the original idea behind SageMath was to have a substitute for Magma. So if you know Magma lots of things in Sage should be familiar.

Comment: quid, thanks. Sage does have the Mass Formula for positive quadratic forms because Jonathan Hanke got involved. However, he kept trying to get me to write the neighbor method to construct spinor genus and genus of a positive integral quadratic form. As I did not know Sage, or know the neighbor method well enough, it never got done. It did get done in Magma, long ago; there were errors when a high power of 2 divided the discriminant, but there were ways (slow) to double check and get correct results.

Comment: @WillJagy interesting. I kind of suspected you might likely know some of the persons involved.

Comment: +1. While it isn't necessary for large integers, the gmp library is usable in python as gmpy and does provide good functions for next_prime, is_prime, gcd,...

Answer (score 7):

> What computer languages might one recommend for, say, investigations in number theory?

I find [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) ideal, 
e.g.:

- "[Mod sequences that seem to become constant; and the number 316](https://mathoverflow.net/q/191518/6094)"
- "[Does 53 diverge to infinity in this Collatz-like sequence?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/240392/6094)"

But: (a) there is a huge start-up learning curve, and (b) Mathematica is not free. Because of the latter, I recommend [Sage](http://www.sage.com/us) / [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/):

---

[image: MultiGraph]


<sup>Multi-edge graph: "All pairs of characters in the sentence 'I am a cool multiedge graph with loops.'"</sup>

---

Comment: Hi, Joseph. Is that the same as sage? I have that at home but have never figured out how to write a many-line program.

Comment: Website seem to show an online calculator version; they also show titles of books for beginners. Good start.

Comment: @WillJagy likely yes, except if you are into accounting, and have that [Sage](http://www.sage.co.uk/). // I second the recommendation for SageMath. In fact I wrote an answer recommending it in parallel.

Comment: @WillJagy The version of Sage that runs in a terminal is a bit hard for me to use (I think you save a text file with your long programs and load it, to access the functions you've defined). But they've put a lot of work into creating an online interface (SageMathCloud) and it is *very* nice to use (in my opinion).

Answer (score 4):

For beginning number theory, [Art of Problem Solving has an online course](http://artofproblemsolving.com/school/course/intro-numbertheory). The textbook used with it, *[Introduction to Number Theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/intro-number-theory)* by Matthew Crawford, can be used alone for self-study. (I have not used the course. I have used the textbook.) I tutored a very advanced 9-year-old using this book, and enjoyed it.

I see they also have an [intermediate number theory course](http://artofproblemsolving.com/school/course/intermediate-numbertheory).

Comment: Thanks. Here is the one number theory question by this student, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103981/show-that-if-p-is-a-prime-satisfying-np2n-then-binom2nn-equiv-0-mod  Otherwise it is mostly complex analysis. I did reply to her email, trying to get her to arrange some project with faculty there.  http://math.stackexchange.com/users/393345/janitha357

Comment: That's above my head (for now).

Comment: I try to show them Pascal's triangle when possible. Lots of these students on MSE try to argue purely formally, never really get their hands dirty. The worst thing is that they don't draw graphs...I put a website where they can download a pdf of graph paper, print that out, actually draw $y = 2 x^2 + x + 3$ or whatever. they never do.

Answer (score 4):

Seconding/complementing other answers: Python (and/or Python as a part of Sage) has a command-line interface (on Linux/Unix and on Mac OS) that *does* allow defining variables, pre-loading files that set things up, and so on. Python (and, thus, Sage) has built-in large integers that are easier to use than C++ large integers (in my opinion). And freely available.

EDIT: ... and (I forgot to mention) it is quite easy to use the built-in graphing and graphical capabilities of Sage (especially in the "notebook" mode).

Comment: Right. The GMP interface for C++ still requires knowing  odd looking constructions rather than simple operator overloading. I have mostly worked out what I need. I did want to offer the student something that she might actually do, but that may be too optimistic.

Comment: @WillJagy, and, in my experience, the weak typing of Python/Sage is less oppressive/confusing to inexperienced students than the typing in C++. Beginners often are unable to use/see the benefits of any typing and/or pre-declaring variables, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Benjamin Hutz has a recent book that could be appropriate: [An Experimental Introduction to Number Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/amstext-31).

> This book presents material suitable for an undergraduate course in elementary number theory from a computational perspective. It seeks to not only introduce students to the standard topics in elementary number theory, such as prime factorization and modular arithmetic, but also to develop their ability to formulate and test precise conjectures from experimental data. Each topic is motivated by a question to be answered, followed by some experimental data, and, finally, the statement and proof of a theorem. There are numerous opportunities throughout the chapters and exercises for the students to engage in (guided) open-ended exploration. At the end of a course using this book, the students will understand how mathematics is developed from asking questions to gathering data to formulating and proving theorems.

Regarding languages, in the [preface](https://bookstore.ams.org/cdn-1599806593742/amstext-31/%7E%7EFreeAttachments/amstext-31-pref.pdf) he mentions the following:

> The book is not tied into any one computer algebra system, and there are several freely available. The systems SageMath and PARI/GP are two excellent freely
> available systems. Similarly, Mathematica, Maple, or other commercial software
> could also be used. Because there are many excellent tutorials for each of these
> systems freely available, they will not be presented in this book.

Comment: That seems quite good. In most of the MSE number theory questions by relative beginners, it is clear the jumble of symbols has little meaning for them. Also, they mostly refuse to do experiments I suggest. This could be a winner.

Comment: Attempting to order a print copy. There is probably a way to tell the ams bookstore page that I am already a member and get it to charge the sale price. Contents look really good,

Comment: @WillJagy: glad it looks useful! Another recent book worth looking into is Weissman's *An Illustrated Theory of Numbers*. See https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/14131/376.

Comment: I have Weissman. I learned Conway's Topograph diagram from his little book, plus answered a dozen questions of  type $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 = target $  when the quadratic form is indefinite. I can't see that any MSE student has ever drawn such a diagram

Comment: @WillJagy: by the way, for Conway's Topograph see also Hatcher's draft text [Topology of Numbers](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNpage.html), but I guess you already know that from https://mathoverflow.net/q/285969/2312.

Comment: Right. I found helpful details there and in Stillwell  http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387955872          From years of these, I believe I have the best possible way to include everything in a few diagrams on ordinary copier paper, a "river" diagram that respects the oriented automorphism group of the indefinite form, then "tree" diagrams  to show where a specified target shows up. Would love to get the drawing process automated, I don't know any programming related to graphics

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: Just a note, but the 2009 article by Benedetto, your good self et al, *Computing points of small height for cubic polynomials* appears as entry [5] in the Bibliography on p. 299. You may also be interested to know that Hutz's book has a chapter on dynamical systems.